# Remote config suddenlly not working in my existing android apps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

Last week i got this email

> We’re writing to let you know we’re launching real-time config updates, a new Remote Config feature. To make sure you can seamlessly use this feature, we’ll enable the Firebase Remote Config Realtime API within your projects that currently use Firebase Remote Config between March 20 and April 3, 2023.
>
> You are receiving this message because one or more of your Firebase projects are using Firebase Remote Config.
>
> What do you need to know?
> Enabling the new Firebase Remote Config Realtime API ensures existing Remote Config users have access to real-time features, e.g., make real-time configuration updates to app instances.

But today i realize that my apps are not fetching any remote config values and returning empty values.

Answer (score 0):

The introduction of that new server-side API does not affect existing apps that use the APIs that already existed. Or at least, it shouldn't...

I recommend you check for other causes, such as changes you made to your code or to the actual configuration values. If you are certain this problem originates in Firebase, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't know but why my app was unable to fetch value in my workplace network either its issue of IP but strange its working in other networks now.